# Using WDK 10 to sign an existing DLL for Windows 10

Tags: windows, dll, usb, wdk, driver-signing

I'm using a Cypress FX3 controller over USB 3 and I've had success with it on Windows 7 by modifying Cypress's driver .inf file to identify my device and then signing the driver package. Unfortunately, this method doesn't meet the more stringent signing requirements for drivers in Windows 10 [1].

I downloaded Windows' new WDK 10 and have been trying to go through the process of signing the driver with this new tool, but it doesn't seem to want to sign a pre-built DLL. Rather, it expects me to have source code files I can build into my own DLL, but I can't exactly expect Cypress to hand over their source code.

Does anyone know if signing an existing driver DLL is supported in WDK 10 or if that functionality has been removed to close a security loophole? Do I simply have to wait for Cypress to publish a driver compatible with Windows 10 v1607+?

For anyone wondering, I have already disabled secure boot and the driver signing verification on my machine for testing. The version 1.2.3 drivers from Cypress work with my device on Windows 10 except for the driver signing issue - but I would prefer if I didn't have to ask customers to disable secure boot in order to install the drivers for my device.

Thanks in advance,

Sheldon

[1] https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_hardware_certification/2016/07/26/driver-signing-changes-in-windows-10-version-1607/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SignTool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to directly sign a DLL without needing to compile anything.  I have never heard of a signed DLL being necessary in a driver, though.  I wrote a [big article](http://www.davidegrayson.com/signing/) about this stuff that might find helpful.

Comment: +1 mostly for the article you've written (I've been working off of it for the past few weeks and I'm very thankful for your time and effort spent in writing it!)